# Update Json value in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, google-sheets-api

I am trying to specify a name for my google spreadsheet api. This is done in the 'title' key value. I have tried with the below but it adds a new key to the existing json. Is there a way to get to the `"title": ""` and update that value with the `new_date` item?

```
prev_date =  datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(1)
new_date = str(prev_date.isoformat())
res = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "addSheet": {
        "properties": {
          "title": ""
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
res['title'] =  new_date
print (res)
```

This is the output:

```
{'requests': [{'addSheet': {'properties': {'title': ''}}}], 'title': '2016-12-29'}
```

This is what I would like it to be:

```
{'requests': [{'addSheet': {'properties': {'title': '2016-12-29'}}}]}
```

Comment: Just follow the references to the nested dictionary: `res['requests'][0]['addSheet']['properties']['title'] = new_date`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Martijn Pieters

Comment: What does this have to do with `json`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the structure you mentioned, the `title` key  that you need to modify is more nested than what you are providing with.

You need to make the following change:

```
prev_date =  datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(1)
new_date = str(prev_date.isoformat())
res = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "addSheet": {
        "properties": {
          "title": ""
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
res['requests'][0]['addSheet']['properties']['title'] =  new_date
print (res)
```

Where:

- `'requests'` value is a `list`
- `0` is the first item in the list (and the only item)
- `'addSheet'` is the key in the dictionary that is the value of the item in the list in the `0` index
- `'properties'` is the key in the above dictionary
- `'title'` is the key in the above dictonary, and the one you need upon your request

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrectly indexing your JSON object and adding a new key named 'title' in the root of the object, while you are trying to update the value inside the array. In your case, you should be accessing `res['requests'][0]['addSheet']['properties']['title'] = new_date`

Answer (score 1):

I now realize I can pass my variables directly in the json.

```
prev_date =  datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(1)
new_date = str(prev_date.isoformat())
req = {
"requests": [
{
"addSheet": {
"properties": {
"title": new_date
}
}
```